# Multiple where clause in link separated with or

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the following scenario:

A user can pick from any one of the following options during a search:

- 0
- 1-3
- 4-6
- 7-9
- 10-12
- 12+

say they picked 0, 4-6 and 12+

The SQL where statement would be:

```
Where (total_count = 0
OR (total_count >= 4 AND total_count <= 6)
OR total_count > 12)
```

Now to get these values I am iterating through a checkbox list collection so was trying:

```
query = query.Where(tc => tc.total_count >= 4 && tc.total_count <= 6);
```

But this was adding an AND between the statements, how could I add an or. I realise that I could potentially build a list with integers in and do a contains but I don't know how much the 12+ would potentially go up to.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see the problem with adding "OR", all the "WHERE" clause need is a predicate(something that return true or false". or maybe i missed the point

Comment: Found the solution on http://albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem with adding "OR". all the "WHERE" clause need is a predicate(something that return true or false". or maybe i missed the point.

regarding you SQL example the equivalent would be

```
    query.Where(tc=> tc.total_count == 0 || (tc.total_count >= 4 && tc.total_count <= 6) || tc.total_count > 12)
```

Comment: The issue I had was that I was getting the values from a checkbox so it changes.  I stumbled across http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx which sorted my probelm out